Updating user to whom task is assigned
Can we change/update user to whom task is assigned in SharePoint 2010 style workflow?
Let's say a task is assigned to user User1 and I want to assign it to User2. If I update that particular item in Tasks list using PowerShell and change the user, will it work?
